# Optimize ListView backed up custom implemented BaseAdapter by caching View generated

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am showing enormous views on tabs formed with listview. ListView gets its data from an Adapter extending BaseAdapter. Every time, I move back and forth tabs, the Pager tends to create view in ListView again and again, wasting my precious CPU.

OK, so I tried using parentView.getChild(atIndex) in getView of BaseAdapter but that just ruins the view on scrolling the ListView.

Question, any way to optimize the performance by caching the view?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ListView already recycles views. The recycled view will be the View parameter in your adapters getView method.

You should also consider using the ViewHolder pattern to avoid a bunch of findViewById calls. See this link for more details http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

**Edit:** Here's some more references I was looking at tonight for optimizing ListViews:

http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: Dude, you are awesome. Good_Karma_for_cory++

Comment: Aah, the answer is not what I thought it was. My bad, I mis-read your comment. But you are correct, using ViewHolder pattern helped out a bunch, except that where value is missing for next view it uses garbage data from previous view. Still thanks a lot. It definitely helps in improving performance.

Comment: Did you look at the getView() method in that link and see how they are reusing the recycled views and using the set/getTag methods to save references to the child views that need to be updated per row? Unless I misunderstood your question it seemed like this would solve your problem. I just watched a Google I/O video on ListViews tonight and they specifically said you shouldn't try to cache views since ListViews are already highly optimized for efficiency. Let me see if I can find the video.

Comment: Sorry just saw your update. If the data is missing you might want to clear out the old data. Few more links coming shortly.